# Probability that the withdrawn balls are the same color

Tags: probability, probability-theory

### Question

> An urn contains $n$ white and $m$ black balls, where
>   $n$ and $m$ are positive numbers.
>
> 1. If two balls are randomly withdrawn, what is  the probability that they are the same color?
> 2. If  a  ball  is  randomly  withdrawn  and  then
>      replaced before the second one is drawn, what
>      is the probability that the withdrawn balls are
>      the same color?

#### My Approach

1. Probablity$$=\frac{\binom {n}{2}\,+\,\binom {m}{2}}{\binom {n+m}{2}}$$

> Either choosed $2$ color from white $(n)$ or 2 from black $(m)$

2.Probablity$$=\frac{\binom {n}{1}\,*\,\binom {n-1}{1}\,+\,\binom {m}{1}\,*\,\binom {m-1}{1}}{\binom {n+m}{2}}$$

> first choosed $1$ ball from black ,then $1$ from the remaining and did the same for 
>    white ball .Am i correct?

Comment: No, when you have an exclusive or, you need to add, not multiply, so your numerators are incorrect.

Comment: @quasi sorry i replaced $+$ with $*$

Comment: Also, for the second one, what is the $n-1$ all about?

Comment: Also, if you replace a ball after it is withdrawn, you have the same number of balls you started with during the second selection.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig will it be $$=\frac{\binom {n}{1}\,*\,\binom {n}{1}\,+\,\binom {m}{1}\,*\,\binom {m}{1}}{\binom {n+m}{2}}$$?

Comment: The second one shouldn't use combinations, since you can get the same ball again.

Comment: Your numerator is correct, but you are selecting from $n + m$ balls each time in the second problem.

Comment: @quasi please give your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one:
$$\large{\frac{\binom{m}{2}+\binom{n}{2}}{\binom{m+n}{2}}}$$
Explanation:

- $\large{\binom{m+n}{2}}$ ways of selecting two balls.

  $\large{\binom{m}{2}}$ ways of selecting two black balls.

  $\large{\binom{n}{2}}$ ways of selecting two white balls.

For the second one:
$$\frac{m^2+n^2}{(m+n)^2}$$
Explanation:

- $(m+n)^2$ ways of selecting two balls, one at a time, with replacement.

  $m^2$ ways of selecting two black balls.

  $n^2$ ways of selecting two white balls.